# Limit of $\sum_{i=1}^k a_iz_i^n$ as $n\to\infty$ where $|z_i| = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers

Let $z_1, ..., z_k \in S^1\setminus\{1\}$, $a_1, ..., a_k\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ with $z_i\neq z_j$ for $i\neq j$, and consider the sequence of the form $b_n = \sum_{i=1}^k a_iz_i^n$. Is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ can never exist?

I think that if we assume $z_1, ..., z_k$ are all roots of unity, then $b_n$ must be non-constant and periodic, so the limit doesn't exist.

If $z$ isn't a root of unity, it's known that $\{z^n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $S^1$, so I think that in this case the limit also won't exist, but I'm not sure if the density of two such terms won't "cancel out".

Comment: I guess you also want to assume that the $z_i$ are all different from each other to avoid trivial counterexamples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wlog $k \ge 2$ and we first assume $a=a_1+..+a_k \ne 0$ and show that $b_n$ cannot converge and then we reduce the case $a=0$ to the previous case in $k-1$ variables so completing the problem.

So let $a \ne 0, b_n \to b$

Let $g_m(z)=1-\Pi_{q=1}^k(1-z\bar z_q^m)=\sum_{r=1}^kc_{rm}z^r$ and note that $g_m(z_q^m)=1, q=1,..k$, hence multiplying with $a_q$ and summing $q=1,...k$ one gets that $\sum_{r=1}^kc_{rm}b_{rm}=a$

Let $c_m=\sum_{r=1}^kc_{rm}$, so $c_mb-a=\sum_{r=1}^kc_{rm}(b-b_{rm})$ and since obviously $|c_{rm}| \le 2^k$ as they are $r$ symmetric sums in $\bar z_q^m$ and $b_{rm} \to b, m \to \infty$ for each $r=1,..k$, one gets that $c_m \to a/b, m \to \infty$ (and of course $b \ne 0$)

But now $c_m=g_m(1)=1-\Pi_{q=1}^k(1-\bar z_q^m)$ so one gets that $d_m=\Pi_{q=1}^k(1-\bar z_q^m)$ converges and that is easily shown to be impossible as in the one dimensional case (if $y_q=\bar z_q$, the image of $(y_1^m, y_2^m,..y_k^m)$ in the $k$-torus depends of the equivalence classes under the relation $y_q$~$y_r$ iff $y_q/y_r$ is a root of unity, so one either has the case where all $y_q$ are roots of unity and the image hence $d_m$ is periodic, or one gets density on each equivalence class that is not $1$ independently of the other and periodicity again for the roots of unity, and $d_m$ cannot converge in this case either -see below for more detail ***)

Assume now $a=0$ so $c_mb \to 0$, but by the above $c_m$ cannot converge so $b=0$; and let $y_q=z_q\bar z_k, q=1,..k-1$. Then with $f_n=\sum_{q=1}^{k-1}a_qy_q^n$, one has $f_n+a_k=f_n+a_kz_k^n\bar z_k^n=b_n\bar z_k^n \to 0$ as $b_n \to 0$, hence $f_n \to -a_k$ and $a_1+a_2+..a_{k-1}=-a_k \ne 0$ so we are in the previous case for the $k-1$ circle numbers $y_q$ and we showed that was impossible, hence we are done!

Note - the algebraic manipulations and ideas above are adapted from Turan's famous method of power sums where various interesting things about the sequence $b_n$ (in the more general case $\min |z_q|=1$) are proved that way

*** as per comments request, we will elaborate a little on the fact that if $|y_q|=1, y_q \ne 1, q=1,..,k$, then $d_m=\Pi_{q=1}^k(1-y_q^m)$ cannot converge; first we note that either $y_1^m$ is periodic or dense (while $|\Pi_{q=2}^k(1-y_q^m)| \le 2^{k-1}$), so choosing an appropriate subsequence for which $y_1^m \to 1$ (or of course $y^m=1$ in the periodic case), if $d_m$ converges, then $d_m \to 0$.

Then if there are roots of unity among the $y_q$, picking $N$ the lcm of all their orders and considering only $mN+1$ powers, those terms become constant ($y_q^n=1, n|N$ then $y_q^{mN+1}=y_q$) with the corresponding product constant non zero, while the other terms are of the type $y_q(y_q^N)^k$ so we apply uniform distribution results to $y_q^N$ instead and let's rename them $w_q, q=1,..l \le k$.

Assuming $l \ge 1$ (so there is at least one nonroot of unity among the $y_q$ as otherwise we are done) the group generated by $w_q$ is finitely generated free abelian, so it has a bunch of generators (which we can rename) $w_1,..w_r, r \le l$ and the others are of the type $w_q=w_1^{n_1}..w_r^{n_r}$ for fixed numbers $n_1,..n_r$ depending on $q$; now by general theory and actually not hard to prove with Weyl criterion, $(w_1^m,..w_r^m)$ are dense in the $r$ Torus so we can pick any combination of $r$ unit circle numbers we want and approximate it well infinitely many times, and then we can clearly do this with $y_1w_1^m,...,y_rw_1^m$ instead by rotating back.

So (with the usual principal argument in $[-\pi,\pi]$) we can choose to approximate well infinitely many times, such $r$ circle numbers, $\alpha_1,..\alpha_r$ with the property $|\arg \alpha_q|>\delta>0$ and also $|\arg {y_q(y_1^{-1}\alpha_1^{n_1}..y_r^{-1}\alpha_r^{n_r}})|>\delta$ for the particular $q$ for which $w_q=w_1^{n_1}..w_r^{n_r}$; hence approximating as above well enough we get that all $|\arg(y_q^{mN+1}|>\delta/2$ on that particular subsequence, so $1-y_q^{mN+1}$ stays away from $1$ on that particular subsequence of $m$'s and $d_m$ cannot converge to zero either.

Comment: I don't fully understand the part with $(y_1^m, ..., y_k^m)$ and equivalence classes under relation $y_q\sim y_r$ iff $y_q/y_r$ is a root of unity, the rest is clear to me. Could you elaborate a little more about that?

Comment: added; $y_1^m,...y_k^m$ can behave quite complicated on the $k$ Torus, but there are $r_1$ coordinates where they are jointly dense, $r_2$ coordinates where they are separately dense depending on the first $r_1$ (so not necessary jointly eg if $y_2=y_1^2$ non-roots of unity, then both $y_1^n$ and $y_2^n$ are separately but not jointly dense) and then $r_3$ coordinates corresponding to roots of unity where they are periodic) and this shows that we can make the product stay away from zero on an infinite subsequence, while it can be made close to zero on the first term on another subsequence

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof when $a_i>0$ : suppose that $(b_n)$ converges and let $\sigma_1:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be such that $(z_1^{\sigma_1(n)})_{n\geqslant 0}$ converges to a limit point $\ell_1$ of $(z_1^n)_{n\geq 0}$, then we can construct $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $(z_i^{\sigma(n)})_{n\geqslant 0}$ converges to some $\ell_i$ (this is the same limit as before when $i=1$). We can suppose without loss of generality that $(\sigma(n+1)-\sigma(n))_{n\geqslant 0}$ is strictly increasing so that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}b_{\sigma(n+1)-\sigma(n)}=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i$. Since $(b_n)$ converges, then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}b_n=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i$ and therefore
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k a_i\ell_i=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}b_{\sigma(n)}=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \implies \sum_{i=1}^k a_i(l_i-1) = 0$$
Since $\text{Im}(l_i-1) \leq 0$ and $l_i\in S^1$ for all $i$, we need to have $l_1 = ... = l_k = 1$, so that $1$ is the only limit point of $(z_1^n)_{n\geqslant 0}$, therefore $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}z_1^n=1$ and $z_1=\frac{z_1^{n+1}}{z_1^n}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}1$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: That's a very nice proof.